# The GitKraken "commit graph" contains a mix of identicons or author's avatar

Tags: gitkraken

The commit graph of GitKraken sometimes contains identicons while some others contains the author's profile avatars for commits (I'm testing with GitHub, but I don't think it's specific to this instance).

I just can't figure out what makes GitKraken to decide (if any choice?) which one to show in each cases?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GitKraken uses [Gravatar](https://gravatar.com) to decide which icons to show. You can read this up in the GitKraken [help page on profiles](https://support.gitkraken.com/start-here/profiles/) and [their FAQ (How do I change the avatar associated with my commits?)](https://support.gitkraken.com/faq).

From [the Gravater documentation](https://de.gravatar.com/support/gravatar-locations/):

> Gravatar uses your email address to provide your image to other sites.

Thus, the committer email adress set up in your git config will decide which icon will be shown.

Comment: So unless I can convince everyone else on my team to join gravatar, I'm just left with random images in the change history?

Comment: Yes. By now, you can also display the authors initials instead of avatars by checking the respective checkbox in `Preferences`->`UI Preferences`.

Comment: Is there a local cache where I could supply avatars of my team mates? or a mapping file of email to URL of a png file?